# Android - Floating Action Button over the top of a Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, floating-action-button

When i put the Floating Action Button over the top of a Google Map it stops me from being able to interact with the map.

The layout is match_parent for height and width, so the FAB takes up all of the screen, but it does the same on my other Fragments (without Google Maps) and i can interact with Views behind those FAB's. When the FAB is on a Fragment with a Google Map on it, i cannot interact with any Views behind the FAB.

I am using this Floating Action Button:
https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: hey please paste your xml code here :-)

Comment: here is the xml:  http://pastebin.com/pKGAJKM5

Comment: Just asking...... How many floating action buttons do you want ?

Comment: Btw just put your fab with wrap content on width n height n try it out and have just one fab in your layout for trial

Comment: hey guys, i tried that and it still only let me interact with any views outside of the FAB.  I have about 300dp left below it and i could interact with that part of the map but not with anything inline with the match_parent width of the FAB.  ;(

Comment: penta, unfortunately it does the same with one or two

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `android:focusable="false"` and `android:clickable=false` to your FloatingActionButton. But seriously though, why do you want to make your Floating Action Button take up the whole screen?

Comment: The actual button doesn't take up the whole screen, it's 40dp in the top left corner, the FAB has buttons that drop down once it is pressed, and these take up the whole screen (although are initially hidden).  So the layout for the whole FAB, and hidden buttons, take up the whole screen when the FAB is tapped, so i the whole thing has to have match_parent for width and height.  

It works on my other fragments though, everything behind the FAB is able to be interacted with when the FAB is open and closed.  It's just when there's a Google Map behind the FAB that i can't interacte with anything

Answer (score 1):

So what i ended up doing was putting the fragment in an Activity with a ViewPager and put the FAB in the xml for that Activity, this allows me to interact with the map in the Fragment that the ViewPager holds

Answer (score 0):

tried your code, i could not help much as there are many drawables which you are using n which i dont have, i recomend u use this library for floating action buttons, i am using the same and they work just fine.

The syntax is

```
 <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonFloat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="#C2185B"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="#FF4081"
            fab:fab_colorRipple="#F06292" />
```

and `compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'`

Answer (score 0):

You should add these lines programatically after finish dealing with the FAB and before it gets rendered.

```
fabButton.setFocusable(false);
fabButton.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `ToggleListener` to your `FloatingActionMenu` and then you can hide the buttons that takes over the screen.

```
fabMenu.setOnMenuToggleListener(new FloatingActionMenu.OnMenuToggleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMenuToggle(boolean opened) {
                if(opened){
                    fltActsettings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    fltActnotifications.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    fltShowMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    fltActCreateRequest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    fltActHistory.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    fltActsettings.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    fltActnotifications.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    fltShowMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    fltActCreateRequest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    fltActHistory.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
```